# Facebook batch process error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm implementing the Facebook batch process to upload multiple images with the single request.
I'm using the simple example given at:

And my code is as follow:

```
$str = "curl 
     –F  ‘access_token=…’ \
     -F  ‘batch=[{
                  “method”:”POST”, \
                  “relative_url”:”ALBUM_ID/photos”, \
                  “body”:”message=My photo” \
                  "attached_files":"file1" \
                 },
                 {
                  “method”:”POST”, \
                  “relative_url”:”ALBUM_ID/photos”, \
                  “body”:”message=My photo” \
                  "attached_files":"file2" \
                 },
                 {
                  “method”:”POST”, \
                  “relative_url”:”ALBUM_ID/photos”, \
                  “body”:”message=My photo” \
                  "attached_files":"file3" \
                 },
                ]’
     -F  ‘file1=@3.jpg’ \
     -F 'file2=@2.jpg' \
     -F 'file3=@1.jpg' \
    https://graph.facebook.com "
exec($str, $error);
```

And when I check my `$error` variable it shows me that `"curl: -F not found"`.

And if I echo that string on browser and then copy / past on terminal does work for me.

I'm not getting why this is not working with PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: try to remove "\" from the end of each lines.

Comment: Nope, not working at all.. gives me error like "-F host not found"  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, try to do following:

```
$str = str_replace("\n"," ",$str);
exec($str);
```

This should work..

Comment: YEAH, thanks.. that did the job...
But why copy / past work and on browser it would not ?

Comment: Try to use
echo '<pre>'; print_r($str); echo '</pre>';
You'll come to know the reason :)